# If row in Dataframe contains certain string delete

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have to delete values in row of a dataframe if they contain a certain string. 
Problem is that row is very long and contains text.

Loop does not work and put index in a list and then use .drop on index does also not work.

```
column1
8
8
8
8 total       <-------- This must be deleted
8
8 
8 
8
8
...
```

Thanks

Comment: check `pandas` ,[`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) -->`series[~series.str.contains('total')]`

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your dataframe is called `df`. Then use:

```
df_filtered = df[~df['column1'].str.contains('total')]
```

**Explanation**:

`df['column1'].str.contains('total')` will give you an array of the length of the dataframe column that is `True` whereever `df['column1']` contains `'total'`. With `~` you swap the `True` and `False` values of this array. And finally with `df_filtered = df[...]` you take only the lines, for which `'total'` is not included.

Comment: you can add 'case = False' to the statement if you do not care about case. You might also need to add 'na = False' ,just in case you have some nas in the column.  df[~df['column1'].str.contains('total', case = False, na = False)]

Answer (score 2):

if i understood it correctly, i have an small example below where the dataFrame is called `df` and i want to remove the `mixfruit` to be searched and deleted.

```
>>> df
       name  num
0     apple    5
1    banana    3
2  mixfruit    5
3    carret    6
```

One way is as other mentioned can go with `str.contains` as follows ..

```
>>> df[~df.name.str.contains("mix")]
     name  num
0   apple    5
1  banana    3
3  carret    6
```

You can use `isin` as well, which will drop all rows containing string

```
>>> df[~df['name'].isin(['mixfruit'])]
     name  num
0   apple    5
1  banana    3
3  carret    6
```

However, you can achieve the same as follows...

```
>>> df[df['name'] != 'mixfruit']
     name  num
0   apple    5
1  banana    3
3  carret    6
```